# "How to download a PDF of an Android layout with RecyclerView, capturing both visible and invisible data?"

Tags: android, kotlin, pdf, android-recyclerview

When attempting to download the entire layout, I faced an issue where the downloaded content was limited to the layout data itself. Moreover, when extracting data from the RecyclerView, only the currently visible data was included in the download. This limitation prevents the comprehensive capture of the complete content within the RecyclerView, and I'm seeking guidance on how to ensure the entire layout, including all data within the RecyclerView, is successfully downloaded.

**Activity Code:**

```
private fun createPdf() {
    val pdfDocument = PdfDocument()
    val pageInfo = PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(
        binding.downloadRecyler.width,
        binding.downloadRecyler.height,
        1
    ).create()

    val page = pdfDocument.startPage(pageInfo)
    val canvas = page.canvas
    binding.downloadRecyler.draw(canvas)
    pdfDocument.finishPage(page)

    val timeStamp = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(Date())
    val pdfFileName = "${userName}_PDF_$timeStamp.pdf"

    val directory = File(
        Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "Attendance app"
    )

    if (!directory.exists()) {
        directory.mkdirs()
    }

    val pdfFile = File(directory, pdfFileName)

    try {
        pdfFile.createNewFile()
        val outputStream = FileOutputStream(pdfFile)
        pdfDocument.writeTo(outputStream)
        pdfDocument.close()
        outputStream.close()

        sendBroadcast(Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(pdfFile)))

        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.pdf_downloaded_successfully), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        showDownloadNotification(pdfFile)

    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error creating PDF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

**XML Code:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".DownloadActivity">

        <!-- ActionBar -->
       <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/actionBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center">

        <!-- Back Button -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btnBack"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_20sdp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center|start"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:src="@drawable/left_arrow" />

        <!-- Download Button -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btnDownload"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center|end"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_download" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- Main Layout -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutDownload"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/actionBar"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/_10sdp">

        <!-- Logo and App Name -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_50sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_logo_transparent" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_18ssp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- User Information -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/actionBar"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:text="Shivam"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <!-- Additional User Details -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtPhone"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Shivam"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_10ssp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtAge"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Shivam"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_10ssp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtYear"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Shivam"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_10ssp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- RecyclerView -->
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/downloadRecyler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Empty Data Image -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/emptyDataImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/data_empty" />

    <!-- ProgressBar -->
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progreesBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Direct can dowload from firebase Database

```
private fun createPdf(selectedYear: String) {
    val myPdfDocument = PdfDocument()
    val myPaint = Paint()

    val pageInfo1 = PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(595, 842, 1).create()
    var page1: PdfDocument.Page? = null
    var canvas1: Canvas? = null

    binding.layoutDownload.post {
        page1 = myPdfDocument.startPage(pageInfo1)
        canvas1 = page1!!.canvas
        canvas1!!.drawColor(Color.WHITE) // Clear the canvas for the first page


        val centerX = (pageInfo1.pageWidth - binding.layoutDownload.width) / 2f


        canvas1!!.translate(centerX, 0f)
        binding.layoutDownload.draw(canvas1!!)
        canvas1!!.translate(-centerX, 0f)

        // Get the height of the drawn layout
        val layoutHeight = binding.layoutDownload.height

        // Calculate the position for additional text below the drawn layout
        val textPaint = Paint()
        textPaint.textSize = 16f
        var yPosition = layoutHeight + 0f // Start below the drawn layout
        //var yPosition = 80f // Start below the drawn layout

        val canvasWidth = pageInfo1.pageWidth.toFloat()

        val marginStart = 30f
        val marginEnd = 30f

        yPosition += 20f // Adjust the Y position for additional spacing

        canvas1!!.drawText("Name: $userName", marginStart, yPosition, textPaint)
        yPosition += 30f

        // Draw mobile number
        canvas1!!.drawText("Mobile: $userPhone", marginStart, yPosition, textPaint)
        yPosition += 30f

        // Draw year
        canvas1!!.drawText("Year: $selectedYear", marginStart, yPosition, textPaint)
        yPosition += 30f


        for (item in list) {
            val dateText = item.date
            val messageText = item.message
            val categoryText = item.category

            val messageWidth = textPaint.measureText(messageText)
            val categoryWidth = textPaint.measureText(categoryText)
            val maxWidth = maxOf(messageWidth, categoryWidth)

            // Check if the current page is finished
            if (yPosition + 80f > pageInfo1.pageHeight) {
                // Start a new page
                myPdfDocument.finishPage(page1)
                val pageInfoNext = PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(595, 842, myPdfDocument.pages.size + 1).create()
                page1 = myPdfDocument.startPage(pageInfoNext)
                canvas1 = page1!!.canvas
                canvas1!!.drawColor(Color.WHITE) // Clear the canvas for the new page
                yPosition = 60f // Reset Y position for the new page
            }

            // Adjust Y position for the text inside the box
            val textYPosition = yPosition + 20f

            // Draw the box (stroke)
            myPaint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
            canvas1!!.drawRect(marginStart, textYPosition - 20f, canvasWidth - marginEnd, textYPosition + 40f, myPaint)

            // Draw the text inside the box with adjusted positions
            canvas1!!.drawText(dateText, marginStart + 10f, textYPosition + 15f, textPaint)

            // Center the message text inside the box
            val messageStartX = (canvasWidth - maxWidth) / 2 + 10f
            canvas1!!.drawText(messageText, messageStartX, textYPosition + 15f, textPaint)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with a Recyclerview is that it only draws enough data for one screen full.

To draw a Recyclerview to a pdf you actually have to draw all of the recycler's content to a more suitable view type (a linear layout is a good fit). You also have to have to be aware of the size of the content if you want to draw it to standard page sizes like A4, etc and aware that a PDF acts as a small size screen.

The fully working example https://github.com/Zardozz/RecyclerviewPdf shows you how to draw the content of a recyclerView to multiple standard pages.

The example does not show how to best fit you recycler's content to the small "screen" size of a PDF. There are various techniques like having the recyclerview adjust it's font size of text draw, to scaling images to setting a scale on the pdf's canvas.

I tend to do a custom layout specifically for a pdf to get the optimal drawing to a pdf.